# What is this binomial sum?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I'm trying to figure out what this sum is equal to:
$$\sum^n_{k=0}k \binom{m-k}{m-n}$$

I thought there are n turns and on each turn you pick 1 object from k objects ($\binom{k}{1}=k$) and also pick $m-n$ objects from $m-k$ objects. So I thought we pick a total of $m-n+1$ objects from $m-k+k=m$ objects, giving 
$$\sum^n_{k=0}k \binom{m-k}{m-n}=\binom{m}{m-n+1}$$
But I plugged in some test numbers and this didn't seem to work. What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation+from+k%3D1+to+n+of+k*((m-k)+choose+(m-n))), it seems to be $m+1 \choose m-n+2$, but I don't know why this is. However, the flaw in your argument seems to be is that ${a \choose b}{c \choose d} \neq {a+c \choose b+d}$.

Comment: Your ${a \choose b}{c \choose d} = {a+c \choose b+d}$ argument is wrong because choosing $a$ objects from a group of $b$ and then $c$ objects from a group of $d$ has a division between the group of $b$ objects and group of $c$ objects since the first $a$ objects must be from the group of $b$ objects and the last $c$ objects must be from the group of $d$ objects, leading to less possibilities than if the objects were all mixed together.

Comment: @NobleMushtak how do I account for this division correctly?

Comment: I had the limit incorrect on the sum. it is fixed now.

Comment: WA tells me $(m (m+1) \binom{m-1}{m-n})/((m-n+1) (m-n+2))$ but I'm not sure how to get that.

Comment: @NobleMushtak how did you get $\binom{m+1}{m-n+2}$ from $(m (m+1) \binom{m-1}{m-n})/((m-n+1) (m-n+2))$?

Comment: @User Whether the sum starts at $k=1$ or $k=0$, it is the same value: for $k=0$, the summand is 0.

Comment: $$\frac{m(m+1){m-1 \choose m-n}}{(m-n+1)(m-n+2)}=\frac{m(m+1)\frac{(m-1)!}{(n-1)!(m-n)!}}{(m-n+1)(m-n+2)}=\frac{(m+1)m(m-1)!}{(n-1)!(m-n+2)(m-n+1)(m-n)!}=\frac{(m+1)!}{(n-m)!(m-n+2)!}={m+1 \choose m-n+2}$$

Comment: Sorry about the formatting error, not sure what happened.

Comment: @NobleMushtak no problem. thank you for explaining. i wish WA would simplify

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let’s look at it a little differently. Suppose that you want to choose a set of $m-n+2$ numbers from the set $A=\{0,1,\ldots,m\}$. If $S$ is such a set, let $k_S$ be the second-smallest member of $S$. Then $S$ has $1$ member smaller than $k_S$ and $m-n$ members larger than $k_S$. For a given $k$ there are $k$ ways to pick one smaller member of the set $A$ and $\binom{m-k}{m-n}$ ways to pick $m-n$ larger members of $A$, so there are

$$k\binom{m-k}{m-n}$$

ways to choose $S$ with $k_S=k$. Summing over the possible values of $k$ gives the total number of such subsets, which is of course

$$\binom{|A|}{m-n+2}=\binom{m+1}{m-n+2}\;.$$

The problem with your approach is that when you choose one of the first $k$ and $m-n$ of the last $n-k$ elements of $[m]$, you’re not just making a selection of $m-n+1$ elements of $[m]$: you’re also specifying a break-point between the first one and the last $m-n$.

Comment: do you mean for a given k there is 1 way to pick the one smallest number of the set?

Comment: Nice combinatorial interpretation!

Comment: @User: No. For a given $k$ there are $k$ members of $A$ that are smaller than $k$. Thus, if you’re simply told what $k$ is, there are $k$ ways to choose the one member of the set that is smaller than $k$. Similarly, there are $m-k$ members of $A$ larger than $k$, so there are $\binom{m-k}{m-n}$ ways to pick $m-n$ of them to be the members of the set that are larger than $k$.

Comment: (For the record: it may be obvious to most, but i took me a while to figure why "the possible values of $k$" are 1 to $n=m-(m-n+2-1-1)$.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This makes perfect sense and is a clever way to think of it.

Comment: @User: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following calculations :
$$
\eqalign{
\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{m-k}{m-n} &= \sum_{k=0}^n (m+1-(m+1-k)) \binom{m-k}{m-n} \cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (m+1)\binom{m-k}{m-n} - \sum_{k=0}^n (m+1-k) \binom{m-k}{m-n} \cr
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (m+1)\binom{m-k}{m-n} - \sum_{k=0}^n (m-n+1) \binom{m-k+1}{m-n+1} \cr
&= (m+1)\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m-k}{m-n} - (m-n+1) \sum_{k=0}^n  \binom{m-k+1}{m-n+1} \cr
}
$$
Let
$$
A=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m-k}{m-n}\ \ \ and\ \ \ B=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{m-k+1}{m-n+1} 
$$
We evaluate first $A$,
$$
\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{m-k}{m-n} \cr
  &= \sum_{0 \le m-k \le n} \binom{m-(m-k)}{m-n} \cr
  &= \sum_{-m \le -k \le -(m-n)} \binom{k}{m-n} \cr
  &= \sum_{0 \le k \le m} \binom{k}{m-n} \cr
  &= \binom{m+1}{m-n+1} \cr
}
$$
Similar calculations for $B$ give
$$
\eqalign {
  B &= \binom{m+2}{m-n+2} \cr
}
$$
To conclude finally that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{m-k}{m-n} = (m+1)\binom{m+1}{m-n+1} - (m-n+1)\binom{m+2}{m-n+2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k {m-k\choose m-n}
= \sum_{k=0}^n k {m-k\choose n-k}
\\= \sum_{k=0}^n k [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{m-k}
= [z^n] (1+z)^m \sum_{k=0}^n k z^k (1+z)^{-k}$$

we see that there is no contribution to the coefficient extractor when
$k\gt n$ so we may extend $k$ to infinity:

$$[z^n] (1+z)^m \sum_{k\ge 0} k z^k (1+z)^{-k}
= [z^n] (1+z)^m \frac{z/(1+z)}{(1-z/(1+z))^2}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^m z (1+z) =
[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{m+1} = {m+1\choose n-1}.$$